# Fancybox 2 - image size stretching

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using the new Fancybox 2 library and have done a simple implementation whereby the user clicks on a link and a image pops up. It is working fine with the exception of the image displaying roughly 50% larger than the actual file.

I have tried setting `autoSize` to `true` but that didn't impact anything. I have also experimented with setting the `width` and the `maxWidth` while having `autoSize` set to `false`.

Has anyone experienced this problem? With Fancybox 1 there was never an issue.

The base code I'm starting with is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        autoSize: true
    });
});
```

The links look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/promo-buttons/fees-payment-large.jpg" class="fancybox">Test One</a>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the API option "fitToView" to false